# ArgumentOutOfRangeException Cabecera DataGridView creado por código

Tags: c#, excepciones, datagrid

Tengo un método de extensión que recibe una parámetro que únicamente sera una lista de una clase de registros de mi DB.

```
public static void AjustarDataGridView<T>(this DataGridView data, T lista)
{
     if ( lista.GetType() == typeof( List<Usuarios> ) )
     {
          data.SettingFormStyle(14);
          data.Columns[0].HeaderText = Resources.Cabecera_Usuario;
          data.Columns[1].HeaderText = Resources.Cabecera_Contrasena;
          data.Columns[2].HeaderText = Resources.Cabecera_Privilegio;
          data.Columns[3].HeaderText = Resources.Cabecera_Empleado;
          data.Columns[4].Visible = false;
          data.Columns[5].Visible = false;
      }
      else if ( lista.GetType() == typeof( List<Empleados> ) )
      {
          data.SettingFormStyle(9);
          data.Columns[0].HeaderText = Resources.Cabecera_SS;
          data.Columns[1].HeaderText = Resources.Cabecera_Nombre;
          data.Columns[2].HeaderText = Resources.Cabecera_Apellidos;
          data.Columns[3].HeaderText = Resources.Cabecera_Telefono;
          data.Columns[4].HeaderText = Resources.Cabecera_Direccion;
          data.Columns[5].HeaderText = Resources.Cabecera_Tipo_Empleado;
          data.Columns[6].Visible = false;
          data.Columns[7].Visible = false;
          data.Columns[8].Visible = false;
          data.Columns[9].Visible = false;
      }
      else if ( lista.GetType() == typeof( List<Productos> ) )
      {
          data.SettingFormStyle(9);
          data.Columns[0].Visible = false;
          data.Columns[1].HeaderText = Resources.Cabecera_Nombre;
          data.Columns[2].HeaderText = Resources.Cabecera_Precio;
          data.Columns[3].HeaderText = Resources.Cabecera_Categoria;
          data.Columns[4].Visible = false;
          data.Columns[5].Visible = false;
      }
      else if ( lista.GetType() == typeof( List<Ingredientes> ) )
      {
          data.SettingFormStyle(9);
          data.Columns[0].Visible = false;
          data.Columns[1].HeaderText = Resources.Cabecera_Nombre;
          data.Columns[2].HeaderText = Resources.Cabecera_Precio;
          data.Columns[3].Visible = false;
      }
}
```

Este método lo ejecuto cada vez que quiero mostrar unos datos en un DGV, el problema llega cuando creo un DGV a código, le añado al DataSource la lista y ya llamo al método de ajustar las cabeceras.

```
private async void Ver_MDI_ModificarEmpleado()
    {
        var lista = await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            return await _apiEmpleado.ObtenerTodosEmpleados();
        });
        crearDGVModificar(lista, 12);
    }

private void crearDGVModificar<T>(T lista, int size) 
{
     panelMDI.Controls.Clear();
     //Creamos el datagriview para mostrar los clientes existentes
     var dgv = new DataGridView()
     {
          AllowUserToAddRows = false,
          AllowUserToDeleteRows = false,
          AllowUserToResizeColumns = false,
          AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill,
          BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(44)))), ((int) 
                (((byte)(44)))), ((int)(((byte)(51))))),
          ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = 
                DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize,
                GridColor = Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(62)))), ((int)(((byte)(120)))), ((int)(((byte)(138))))),
                Name = "dgv",
                ReadOnly = true,
                RowHeadersVisible = false,
                Size = new Size(1194, 590),
                TabIndex = 0,
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
                AutoGenerateColumns = true,
                DataSource = lista

     };

     dgv.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(Resources.Fuente_Letra_Tahoma, 15);
     dgv.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(Resources.Fuente_Letra_Tahoma, 15);
     dgv.RowTemplate.Height = 30;
     dgv.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
     dgv.Click += new EventHandler(this.dataGridView_Click);

     //dgv.SettingFormStyle(15);
     dgv.AjustarDataGridView(lista);

     //Añadimos el datagriview al panel
     panelMDI.Controls.Add(dgv);
}
```

Tengo otro DGV que lo creo arrastrándolo desde la caja de herramientas y le paso una lista y llamo al mismo método y me funciona sin ningún problema...

ESTO FUNCIONA

```
private async Task Ver_MDI_TodosEmpleados()
{
    var frm = Program.NinjectKernel.Get<FormVerDatos>();
    var list = await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            return await _apiEmpleado.ObtenerTodosEmpleados();
        });
    frm.AgregarDatosAlDataGridView(list);
    AgregarFormularioAlMDI(frm);
}

public void AgregarDatosAlDataGridView<T>(T datos)
{            
    dataGridView.DataSource = datos;
    dataGridView.AjustarDataGridView(datos);
}
```

Comment: Has revisado que el número de columnas del grid con respecto al tipo de lista   sea correcto? Es decir`Usuarios` tiene 6 propiedades, `Empleados` 10 y asi sucesivamente?

Comment: si y de hecho si comento el método `AjustarDataGridView` me muestra las cabereas tal como se llaman las columnas en la BD, de hecho te muestro el otro metodo que funciona que llama al mismo método `ObtenerTodosEmpleados()`                                                                
 private async void Ver_MDI_ModificarEmpleado()
        {
            var lista = await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                return await _apiEmpleado.ObtenerTodosEmpleados();
            });
            crearDGVModificar(lista, 12);
        }

Comment: En ese caso (y ya visto que no es por el autogenerate columns) no le veo explicación. Lo que yo haría seria poner un punto de interrupción en el metodo de AjustarDataGridView y ir paso a paso para ver exactamente en que linea me lanza la excepción.

Comment: También lo he hecho y la excepción se produce en la `data.Columns[0].HeaderText = Resources.Cabecera_SS;`(vamos en la primera columna que intenta modificar el nombre)

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre en ese caso es que por alguna razón en ese caso o no le has pasado la lista, o por alguna razón no las ha generado bien. Comprueba en ese punto el número de columnas del grid (data.Columns.Count);.

Comment: Veo que usas Task tambien en algun momento. Revisa a ver si has llamado al metodo de ajuste antes de que le hayas pasado el datasource por algun motivo de sincronización.

Comment: Nose si puedes hacerlo/lograrlo, pero para evitarte esto puedes usar el DVG con el `autogenerate columns` i en la consulta a DB cambiar los nombres de las columnas con `as`, así te evitas todo este codigo engorroso que te esta causando problemas